# What will be the new bar for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, status-completed, style

Any insight how will AU looks with the new not-technically-black bar? IMHO the integration with Canonical's bar may put on-hold such change. How will the bar be integrated with the current UI?

Comment: The new bar? We're raising the bar! *(sad_trombone.mp3)*

Comment: I would wait till see an astonish design from Mateo. *Classic..*

Comment: For reference: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/

Comment: Funniest comment on the blog post: "It’s like Gnome3. 'Letting you do less in more clicks'"

Answer (score 9):

I present to you one possible vision of bringing together the new StackExchange and Ask Ubuntu designs, Featuring:

- New Bar maintaining the designer's vision of a single color for all sites
- A gradual transition using Canonical Mid Aubergine, indicating a Mix of consumer and enterprise focus.
- The space above the bar is removed
- The dotted background is exchanged in favor of http://www.ubuntu.com - Textured gray

[image]

Although maybe it might look more like this:

[image]

With the current design and the current placement of the bar, although many have said the orange clashes it would probably be the least different.

A touch of Aubergine for a drop shadow?

[image]

It should be interesting to see what they come up with, maybe a new design altogether?

---

How about we really shake things up and make a Ubuntu Widget!

[image]

Giving quick links to all the sites available in the Ubuntu bar (maybe even limited updates to select sites).

Comment: I love the last one!

Comment: There should be space between the Canonical and SE bars, they are two different things,  squishing them together doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm guessing they'd go with option 2 you mocked up.

Answer (score 6):

There are two obvious possibilities:

---

[image]

^--- The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ takes precedence.

---

[image]

^--- The Ubuntu bar takes precedence.

Comment: Maybe screenshoots of the main site (orange) would be more useful :)

Comment: @Lucio: _facepalm..._ Did I actually just post screenshots of Meta? I need to wake up...

Comment: The latter looks weird.

Comment: The second option *does* look weird, @3ventic, but it might be required by the agreement between Stack Exchange and Canonical.

Comment: Any reason it needs to extend the full width of the page? The bottom option would look fine if the were a gap between the two bars and the black on was the same width as the page content. Really, it's not all that much different that the current white bar.

Comment: @andrewsomething. That ... that's far too sensible.

Comment: Why don't they name them both superbar and append or prepend in js?  This way, you don't lose screen real-estate, but get both sets of buttons?  #EleganceProblems

Comment: OH, that would be interesting an Ubuntu Widget Icon?! Maybe not what you are talking about @hbdgaf but it gave me the idea

Comment: That could work too.  Just saying.  Don't need nested bars.  Nested bars == poor design decision

Answer (score 4):

Now that the new SE top bar is live it appears that the dark color does not quite fit to the otherwise so nicely made design of our page.

Playing a bit with the colors a [Canonical aubergine](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette) may feel more familiar:

[image]

<sup>Dark Aubergine #2C001E</sup>

[image]

<sup>Mid Aubergine #5E2750</sup>

Comment: I like the look of your avatar there. Didn't realize it had a transparent background.

Comment: @Seth: Transparency only came after the new Top Bar ;)