# Are the new SE bar's colors able to be modified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

I'm looking at the new SE Bar, and while it is indeed spiffy, its colors clash a little with both meta AND the main site's styles.

Is it possible for the SE bar to have customized color pallets for each of the sites, to at least match better with the site colors/design?

(This may be better suited for MSO with a more general question, if it is I will ask there)

Comment: If you only want the change made here, meta.AU is the place. For network wide, mso. ;)

Comment: @Braiam the question is specifically here for AU, yes, however, if other sites end up wanting the same change then a more general question at MSO of site-specific design overrides on the SE bar may be more prudent.  However, it does need to be answered by SE design gurus anyways, so meh

Comment: I don't think this is going to happen. The whole reason they made it black was because they didn't want to make site specific ones.

Comment: I want my White theme! so it melts into the rest of the site better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The goal is to keep the top bar consistent across all SE sites. It was hard to come up with one aesthetic that plays nice with all of our sites' styles. That's why we went with a very dark gray(it's not black!).

However, I don't want to be dogmatic about it. I believe there's wiggle room to tweak the top bar style slightly so it plays nice with a particular SE site. I've changed the translucency a bit on RPG.se and Scifi.se already.

For Ask Ubuntu, I agree the new top bar as of now doesn't look too nice next to the orange top nav section.

I pushed some tweaks to dev server. See the screenshots below. I made the top bar background color to have a hint of orange, I think it looks better with the orange section below.

[image: new topbar color]

new hover bgcolor:

[image: new hover background color]

### Edit:

Thanks to [Takkat's suggestion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7761/what-will-be-the-new-bar-for-ask-ubuntu/7802#7802) I've updated the top bar bgcolor to Canonical's Dark aubergine. See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: See my suggestion using Canonical Aubergine: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7802/3940

Comment: I actually think the darker shade of purple in Takkat's suggestion is better, in this case, perhaps we could use that, Jin?

Comment: @Takkat sorry I missed that. It sure looks a lot better. I've updated the color on dev, you should see it going live within the next 12hours.

Comment: @ThomasW. yep I just updated it.

Comment: Thanks I was unfortunate to put it below the now resolved Meta Q. - Some people said they prefer a white bar, but I think the dark Aubergine fits better to the overall SE theme, and Ubunteros are used to this color too ;)

Comment: I like the last one!

Comment: I like that last one, too.  +1.  Thanks for fixing this, Jin!  :)

Comment: This is now available on the main site, there.  This can be marked as [tag:status-completed] if need be.